# compare two column of two dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, select, dataframe, merge, lookup

I have 2 data frames like :

```
df_out:
a   b     c   d
1   1     2    1
2   1     2    3
3   1     3    5

df_fin:
a   e     f   g
1   0     2    1
2   5     2    3
3   1     3    5
5   2     4     6
7   3     2     5
```

I want to get result as :

```
a   b      c   d  a   e   f   g 
1   1     2    1  1   0   2   1
2   1     2    3  2   5   2   3
3   1     3    5  3   1   3   5
```

in the other word I have two diffrent data frames that are common in one column(a), I want two compare this two columns(df_fin.a and df_out.a) and  select the rows from df_fin that have the same value in column a and create new dataframe that has selected rows from df_fin and added columns from df_out ?

Comment: Is value of `a` unique in `df_out` (from which the other columns have to added)?

Comment: @open-source No, there is values that are the same in column (a)  but I need duplicating rows also .

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join:

```
df = pd.merge(df_out, df_fin, on='a', how='left')
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  1  1  2  1  0  2  1
1  2  1  2  3  5  2  3
2  3  1  3  5  1  3  5
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = df_fin[df_fin['a'].isin(df_out['a'])]
df2 = df_out.join(df1.set_index('a'), on='a')
print (df2)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  1  1  2  1  0  2  1
1  2  1  2  3  5  2  3
2  3  1  3  5  1  3  5
```

Comment: Could you help me to know how should I compare the columns (a ) of two data frames

Comment: pandas\src\join.pyx in pandas._join.left_outer_join (pandas\src\join.c:30181)()

MemoryError:

Comment: number of rows in df_fin is 741000 and number of rows in df_out is 38000 , does it make Memorry Error ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Very large dataframes.

Comment: so how should I do that ?

Comment: is there any way to extract the index of the rows in df_fin  that has the same values in column (a)  with df_out?

Comment: Hard question, I add some solution, but data are really big. So  iam not sure if it works :(

Comment: Yes, I add solution for filtering it by `df_fin[df_fin['a'].isin(df_out['a'])]`

Comment: I've tried that but it gives me the smaller rows of df_out , It should gives me the 38000 rows , it means the df_out is like subset in df_fin , so I don't know why it gives me (2858, 93) instead (38000, 93)

Comment: Hard to answer without data. Are you sure it is subset?

Comment: I've used df_fin column(a) to generate df_out, it mean's at first I extract column a of df-fin and use it for calculating  columns (b, c,d ) of df_out , now I want to combine the result df_out by the original data frame , df_fin  and drop the other rows exclude the rows df_out

Comment: file = r' pth \Data.csv'
#file = r'path \file  17.csv'
with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep = ";", low_memory=False)

Comment: Unfortunately i have to go away for some hours, so I have idea. Can you send me your data (if confidental try anonymize) and your code to my email in my profile and tomorrow try find some solution. Because without data it is really hard.